# What are these called on github?

Tags: github, github-actions

What are these called on GitHub?

[image: Screenshot]

I am *not* looking for recommendations for books, tools, software or libraries, only to know what those represent.

Comment: Badges? Not specific to GitHub though.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Badges.

You find them on [`badges/shields`](https://github.com/badges/shields), sources for [**shields.io**](https://shields.io/)

You will find even more with  [`badges/awesome-badges`](https://github.com/badges/awesome-badges).

As commented, they are not specific to GitHub, and [`services/gitlab/gitlab-pipeline-status.service.js`](https://github.com/badges/shields/blob/a43c98a89a8b8ed17b3c254e123193de3c1655d3/services/gitlab/gitlab-pipeline-status.service.js), for instance, reflects the status of a GitLab pipeline.